# Removing Activities from backStack

Tags: android, back-stack

I have six activities. 
**Lets say A,B,C,D,E,P**

I want to create these flows

**1) A --> B --> C --> D --> E** Move Back  **A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- E**  ***(DONE)***

**2) A --> B --> C --> D --> P**

**P** have two button **Yes** and **No**

**if Yes**
**A <-- P**  **(Removing D,C,B From backstack)**

**if No**
**B <-- P  (Removing D,C From backstack)**

**3) A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> P**

**P** have two button **Yes** and **No**

**if Yes A <-- P  (Removing E,D,C,B From backstack)**

**if No B <-- P  (Removing E,D,C From backstack)**

Comment: Have you got or know the correct answer of your question. I have the same problem and not getting any solution. Please help.

Comment: No, but Navigation controller may be helpful https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to your intent. Also I recommend you to learn all intent flags.
Probably you also should set `launchMode` for your activites A and B in AndroidManifest.xml to `singleTask`

Comment: Where should I use this flag in Activity P and start new Activity but I want to move back to A which is in back stack

Comment: That's why you should use launchMode android:launchMode="singleTask" to those activities

Comment: singleTask will move A and B activity into there own task(Separate backStack) with it i will not able to achieve flow 2 and 3

Comment: Can you just test it?

Comment: You should put it into your intents to A and B activities like: Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Check this out ...here is all the information you may need to learn about moving between activities

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing) : 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing

```
YourCurrentActivity.this.finish();  
     Intent intent1 = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);  
     intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
     startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: If I finish the activity it will be removed from backstack and I will not able to get flow 1.

Comment: yeah you are right I was just showing you the ways you can deal with your activities...call the finish() method when you need it.